# Oracle 10g keeps on Initializing

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am continuously getting Error Code “The ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress”

This is happening ever since I physically deleted a couple of .dbf files

Comment: Are you sure the files you deleted weren't needed?!

Comment: my teamlead told me to remove the database from our local machines after we deployed the application and database on the client's server

Comment: For the future `drop tablespace <tablespace_name> including contents and datafiles`. Messing around in the background causes evil problems sometimes

Comment: Please see the resolution of ORA-01033 here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20444726/2789764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this meself many years ago, deleting the files from disk before DROPing them from within Oracle. The following link has some steps for getting your database to come up after telling Oracle that the files are no longer there: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-drop-tablespace-and-recover-oracle-database-when-accidentally-delete-datafile/.

Comment: Perfect answer! We are business again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Connecting as SYSDBA.  Also look at the relevant lines from the alert-log.  May be at (%ORACLE_BASE%/diag/rdbms/%ORACLE_SID%/%ORACLE_SID%/trace/alert_%ORACLE_SID%.log).

It is likely that oracle is trying to write to or open one of the .dbf files you deleted.  What were the .dbf files?